# Why docker is needed

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-for-windows

I googled and I understand , docker will create an application image with environment setup.

Consider, I have an asp.net application which is already hosted in production.

I see, I can add docker support to an existing asp.net application.

How docker can help me with this, because I have already an environment setup on server. For an asp.net application all I needed mostly is a .net framework to be installed.
Instead to install docker I could install .net framework?

May be my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Docker help in deployment. For small applications, there is no special need to have docker based deployment. If you have large application can and you to push many changes very quickly to production, then choose docker. Docker will help you have a application in creating micoservices and run in any server without bothering about dependencies.